# Underscores - side by side DIVs

Tags: css, wordpress, underscores-wp

I'm playing around with CSS and Underscores. I've tried to place 2 DIV's side by side, but it have no idea how to do that.

[This is what I have and what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypCPK.png)

First idea: set these items as inline elements. 
Easy to say, not easy to do.

There was a very similar question a few years ago:
[Side by Side DIVs in Wordpress/Underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976732/side-by-side-divs-in-wordpress-underscores)

I've tried this code:

```css
.site-branding {
  clear: none;
  display: inline;
  }

.site-title {
  clear: none;
  display: inline;
  }

.main-navigation {
  display: inline;
  }
```

```html
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <div class="site-branding">
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="#" rel="home">Sitename</a></h1>
  </div><!-- .site-branding -->

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"></button>
  </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

with no result (only my header background has disappeared).

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong (still newbie in CSS), so I will be extremely grateful for targeting me.
I thought, that setting clear: none for an element means "do not clear it, regardless of the overriding elements" (quite logical for me).

This is a "clear" Underscores template, so the whole CSS can be found here:
https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <div class="site-branding">
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="#" rel="home">Sitename</a></h1>
  </div><!-- .site-branding -->

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"></button>
<ul>
  <li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
</ul>
  </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.site-branding {
  clear: none;
  display: inline;
  }

.site-title {
  clear: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width:30%;
  }

.main-navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  width:50%;
  }

ul >li{
display: inline-block;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kyc25j9t/)

Comment: Magic. No, seriously though - give this a read. The first answer should provide you with the info you need in order to understand what is going on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block

Comment: Just realized that there is a second part to this that the link does not answer. Width is very important. For the divs to be able to align in a horizontal block - they need a width that does not exceed that of the container. The formula would be something like D1 width + D2 Width + D3 Width ... <= total parent width. Using percent instead of a fixed width allows the divs to scale proportional to their parent.